# How to display coordinates on the static map PNG file as they are received from the GPS in R?

Tags: linux, r, qt, rinside, rgooglemaps

So, currently I have successfully compiled the program (with **RInside**) for plotting coordinates on the static maps of Google (on **Qt**).

Now, I have to plot the coordinates on the map as they are received from the GPS.

**Is it possible somehow to *display* the newly plotted points on the png "on the fly"?

I mean I don't wish to read the png from the *harddisk* every time I receive a new point.**

---

From here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/png/png.pdf

> This package provides an easy and simple way to read,write and display bitmap images stored in the PNG format. It can read and write both ﬁles **and in-memory raw vectors**.

Can this be of any help?

---

```
#include <RInside.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std :: cout << "\nThank-SO :-)\n";

    RInside R (argc, argv);

    std :: string txtA = "library(RgoogleMaps)";
    std :: string txtB = "png(filename='Rg.png', width=480, height=480)";

    std :: string txtC = "lat = c(40.702147,40.718217,40.711614)";
    std :: string txtD = "lon = c(-74.012318,-74.015794,-73.998284)";
    std :: string txtE = "center = c(mean(lat), mean(lon))";
    std :: string txtF = "zoom <- min(MaxZoom(range(lat), range(lon)))";

    std :: string txtG = "MyMap <- GetMap(center=center, zoom=zoom, markers='&40.702147,-74.015794,blues%7C40.711614,-74.012318,greeng%7C40.718217,-73.998284,redc', destfile='My.png')";

    std :: string txtH = "tmp <- PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap,lat=c(40.702147,40.711614,40.718217),lon=c(-74.015794,-74.012318,-73.998284),cex=1.5,pch=20,col=c('red', 'blue', 'green'),add=F)";

    std :: string txtI = "dev.off()";

    R.parseEvalQ (txtA);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtB);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtC);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtD);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtE);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtF);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtG);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtH);
    R.parseEvalQ (txtI);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the `C++` code written with `RInside`.

Comment: please ask if the question isn't clear.

Comment: If you can provide a working example of the code you're using now, you'll probably get much more help. I, for one, am not clear at all one what approach you're using now, or what you've already tried.

Comment: @JeffAllen added code. Is the question clear?

Comment: You are not even using a Qt device. What you have is a basic R script, called from C++. Why?   For the record, the RInside sources have interactive demo using Qt to automatically update a chart based on user input.  And yes, it uses a temporary file for each update.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I looked into qtDensity. They seem to be displaying svg data, and indeed they do use a temporary file. Thankful to you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot the map yourself using the `png` package that you mention (or other tools), then you need some way of mapping between the plot coordinates and the gps coordinates.

If the region of the map is small enough that you are happy with a cartesian approximation then a simple way is to use the `updateusr` function in the `TeachingDemos` package to change the plot coordinates to match with your lat/long information, you will need to know the lat and long for 2 points on the map and you can find their original coordinates using the `locator` function (or if they are corners then you may not need `locator`).  Then you can just use the `points` function to add points on top of the map without needing to reread or replot it.  This is probably fine if the map is of a city or smaller region, but could start to suffer from the approximation if you are trying to show a whole country.

For different projections you can find a way to convert from lat/long to the current plots coordinates, then use `points` with the converted coordinates.  The `sp` package and others may be of help here.

A couple of other packages to consider (if the current functions in the package are not enough, you could still look at the code to get ideas and/or modify the code to use your png file(s)) are `RgoogleMaps` and `ggmap`.

Comment: As Greg suggested, I would check out the package `ggmap`. You can easily grab a Google Maps image of your site based on lat/long, and then overlay your GPS coordinates using `geom_point`.

Comment: @jslefche Thanks I am looking into ggmaps now.

Comment: Greg, your reply was very detailed and helpful. I couldn't have known the other options without your telling. Thanks.